# VS code deleting files after changing tasks.json

Tags: c++

I am having some issue with a project. This is for a course where we have been taught nothing about building a multi-file project and are expecting us to build one. The tasks.json looks as follows:

```
{
    "tasks" :[
        {
          "type" : "cppbuild",
          "label" : "C/C++: g++ build active file",
          "command" : "/usr/bin/g++",
          "args" : [
              "-g",
              "./src/*.cpp",
              "-o",
              "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
          ],
          "options" : {
              "cwd" : "${workspaceFolder}"
          },
          "problemMatcher" : ["$gcc"],
          "group" : {
              "kind" : "build",
              "isDefault" : true
          },
          "detail" : "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version" : "2.0.0"
}
```

I added the "./src/*.cpp" to args to include the cpp files from my src folder (I don't know if this is correct way as we haven't been taught it). Once I ran this, including the header files worked however some of the .cpp files in the ./src directory have been deleted. These aren't in the recycle bin and I have lost a large amount of code. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are correct. The official documentation is here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux) and the mention on what to do with `tasks.json` to allow for multiple files is here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: I have no idea why files were deleted however.

Comment: @drescherjm Ok, that's what I gathered from reading other peoples source code however my files have just disappeared from the ./src directory. What does the "-o" stand for?

Comment: `-o` means output file when using `gcc` / `g++` related: [https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary)

Comment: @drescherjm So, previously, I had the "./src/*.cpp" after the "-o" in the list. Could this have affected it at all?

Comment: Yes that would have destroyed the first file in the list by overwriting it with the executable.

Comment: The -o option of gcc is described here: [https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options) look for `-o file`

Comment: @drescherjm OMG so that's what went wrong! So is there any way to recover this? As it isn't in the recycling bin

Comment: No, I doubt you can recover. I don't think this would use a recycle bin on any OS. On linux with btrfs or zfs you may have a snapshot depending on how this is configured.

Comment: @drescherjm Ok thank you mate. Makes a lot of sense. Wish we had actually been taught what any of this means but ill go study it myself. Thanks again

Comment: @drescherjm Ye I'm really not sure what that means haha. Brutal but I think I'm gonna have to recode it all. On the bright side, I now know not to do that and can recall a fair bit of the code but still. Cheers for the help

Comment: It's likley a case of if you did not understand you likely are not using it anyways. This is usually something you have to configure yourself.

Comment: @drescherjm Ye deffo haven't set it up as this is a beginner course. Cheers for the help I'm gonna get back to coding this again aha. Thanks again

Comment: @drescherjm Unlikely you'll care but I was able to find an older version saved. Life saved. Cheers

Comment: No, that is great that you found an older version.